# SQL used in XML Tags

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to analyze a script under xml tags. It looks like this:

```
<content> 
    <![CDATA[SELECT COL1, COL2 
             FROM TAB1 t1 
             INNER JOIN TAB2 t2 
             WHERE (COALESCE (t1.COLA, t1.COLB, t1.COLC) = ? 
                    OR COALESCE (t1.COLA, t1.COLB, t1.COLC) IS NULL)]]   
</content>
```

Can someone please tell me what is the meaning of "= ?" here? I tried searching it on Google but didn't get any satisfactory result.

Comment: it's the first parameter

Comment: Make sense. Thanks buddy !

Comment: This has nothing to do with XML. IN this case the query just happens to be stored in an XML file. It could have been a JSON or plain text file. `?` is used as a parameter placeholder for clients that *don't* support named parameters. ODBC for example doesn't allow named parameters in queries, only in stored procedures

Comment: Thanks ! That's really helpful.